# Creating mount namespace and isolating mount points redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, namespaces

Trying to get a grasp of all the namespaces and im following this doc https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/mount-namespaces, in here everything was fine until i got to the Creating our mount namespace section and just got LOST.

1. Firstly the command

   ```
   findmnt |grep mapper
   ```

   returns nothing in my case.
2. Secondly i don't understand why we try
   to mount a folder with itself as mount point `mount --bind ${CONTAINER_ROOT_FOLDER}/fakeroot ${CONTAINER_ROOT_FOLDER}/fakeroot`
3. Thirdly i just couldnt
   make the pivot root command work  as it always return invalid
   argument.

So i'm trying to get what am i missing in this tutorial and whats the difference between that and just proceeding with

```
mkdir /tmp/mnt_namespace

sudo mount -t tmpfs none /tmp/mnt_namespace

sudo unshare --mount chroot /tmp/mnt_namespace /bin/bash
```

cause from what i maybe undderstood the writer tried to create a mount namespace without attaching the mount points of the parent user ?

IS this method still vulnerable to processes interacting with each others from different mounts?

Thanks for the help in advance, maybe i have my understanding all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly the command
>
> ```
> findmnt |grep mapper
> ```
>
> returns nothing in my case.

It does not apply to your system. You don't need to grep specifically for `mapper`; the article is telling you to grep for your *root filesystem device,* which only happens to contain the word 'mapper' on Red Hat because of their LVM usage.

> Secondly i don't understand why we try to mount a folder with itself as mount point `mount --bind ${CONTAINER_ROOT_FOLDER}/fakeroot ${CONTAINER_ROOT_FOLDER}/fakeroot`

The purpose is literally to make that path into a mountpoint. As already explained in the article, some operations, such as pivot_root, require a mountpoint root to be given and won't work on ordinary directories.

(I don't think pivot_root is the right function, though – usually I see this being done using `mount --move <path> /` plus some chroot-into-`/` dance.)

> So i'm trying to get what am i missing in this tutorial and whats the difference between that and just proceeding with

One part of the tutorial you've missed is that it has a whole second Linux root filesystem installed in that "fakeroot" directory. It's not just a blank tmpfs directory – if it were just that, you could not `chroot ... /bin/bash` because...there's no /bin/bash inside. If you want to hide the existing OS filesystem then you have to provide a new one (e.g. via debootstrap, or extract an Alpine tarball, or whatever).

The tutorial also creates a *user* namespace to isolate privileges. It calls unshare with `-Ur`, which keeps root (UID 0) identical inside and outside but separates all other UIDs – e.g. UID 1000 inside the namespace will *not* be the same as UID 1000 outside the namespace. You can use mount namespaces without user namespaces, and indeed chroots and containers used to work that way for a long time, but it's significantly less secure.

Keep in mind that there are IPC systems that work outside the filesystem. A mount namespace might isolate the sockets in `/run`, but it *does not* isolate "abstract" sockets (the `@` entries in `netstat -lx`) or loopback TCP sockets – you need a 'network' namespace to isolate those – or legacy SysV IPC, which has its own 'ipc' namespace.

(So, for example, if you have a graphical X11 environment with Xorg running as user 1000 (listening on both a filesystem socket *and* an abstract socket), then you make a chroot using mount namespaces, a process running as UID 1000 inside the chroot will still be able to connect to your Xorg through the abstract socket.)

I'm not sure if the tutorial missed it, but you'll also want to use the `--propagation private` option for unshare, as by default (that is, because of systemd marking `/` as "shared" by default) mounts actually propagate across namespaces.

Comment: i tried to make_private / before creating the mount namespace with -Ur like you said but i still see the mount points of the parent, could you please explain why in this case?

Comment: mount namespaces never start empty – they start as a cloned view, they only allow you to customize that view *after* unshare, e.g. by overmounting `/` or similar. (The make-private also should be done after unshare, not before.)

Comment: so for a use case where i want to have a new mount namespace be fully isolated from the parent, i got no choice to create a mount point which then ill make private so that the children of that have no access to the host, OR go with the chroot when i have a fully fledge OS filesystem, or am i musunderstanding something? Thanks for the followup im a little new to linux so sorry for the stupid questions

Comment: Are namespaces the goal in itself, or are namespaces the _tool_ you chose to accomplish some other goal?

Comment: i would say a tool to accomplish my goal which is isolation.

Comment: Then I'd suggest using `bwrap` or `systemd-run` to build the namespace rather than doing it manually. (bwrap starts with creating an empty tmpfs mount inside its namespace; builds up the minimum required files to run the software using bind-mounts; then finally moves the tmpfs mount over `/` and chroots so that it remains the only thing visible. systemd-run does the opposite where it incrementally blocks access to unwanted parts of the namespace.) Don't confuse "fully isolated" with "empty" – namespaces can be fully isolated but never empty (it is impossible to have no mounts whatsoever).

Comment: thanks, im trying to do it manually for now to understand how all namespaces work. But thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151781/discussion-between-tahtoh-and-u1686-grawity).